# Trying to put that i made in my Tkinter GUI directly into a file

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()'
root.geometry('500x500')
root.title("Auto Assign Widget")

cw=StringVar()
pp=StringVar()
mt=StringVar()
bdt=StringVar()

def printt():   #Print command
    cw1=cw.get()
    pp1=pp.get()
    mt1=mt.get()
    bdt1=bdt.get()
    print("M48")
    print(f"Cu, {cw1}")
    print(f"PP, {pp1}")
    print(f"Mat, {mt1}")
    print(f"Thk, {bdt1}")
    print("%")

def exitt():  #Defining the exit fucntion for the exit button command
    exit()

label_0=Label(root, text="Schmoll Auto Assign Widget", relief='solid')
label_0.place(x=200, y=150)

list1=['Qoz', 'Toz', 'Hoz', '1oz']
droplist=OptionMenu(root, cw, *list1)
cw.set("Copper Weight")
droplist.config(width=15)
droplist.place(x=80, y=240)

list2=['1x106', '1x1027', '1x1080', '1x1067']
droplist=OptionMenu(root, pp, *list2)
pp.set("Pre-Preg Style")
droplist.config(width=15)
droplist.place(x=80, y=280)

list3=['370HR', 'MEG6', 'R6202', 'FR408']
droplist=OptionMenu(root, mt, *list3)
mt.set("Material Type")
droplist.config(width=15)
droplist.place(x=80, y=320)

label_1=Label(root, text='Board Thickness')
label_1.place(x=80, y=360)
entry_1= Entry(root, textvar=bdt)
entry_1.place(x=240, y=360)


but_export = Button(root, text = 'Export', command=printt).place(x=150, y=450)
but_quit = Button(root, text='Quit', command=exitt).place(x=280, y=450)

root.mainloop()
```

And now I would like to try and create another button that sets up a tool path to a directory so i can choose what file i would like to write the information to. Any ideas where i should start looking? I figure that i can do this in Tkinter pretty easy

## with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:

## print('Filename:', filename, file=f)

^ Thats kinda what i had in my but id like to assign it to a button command where maybe i would open the file and then do my GUI stuff, then have it write itself in. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Use better formatting.

Comment: Also, be more clear about what you want. I don't understand what you need.

Comment: If you want to save entries , use 'sqlite' better than 'text file'

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines to your code :

1-import filedialog:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
```

2-in function printt add :

```
text="M48\n"+(f"Cu, {cw1}\n")+(f"PP, {pp1}\n")+(f"Mat, {mt1}\n")+(f"Thk, {bdt1}")+"%"
return text
```

3- Define new function for saving:

```
def file_save():
    text = printt()    
    f = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("text files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))

    if f is None: 
        return
    with open(f, 'r') as original: data = original.read()
    with open(f, 'w') as modified: modified.write(text+"\n" + data)
```

4- create button for Save:

```
but_SaveAs = Button(root, text = 'Save as', command=file_save).place(x=50, y=450)
```

Comment: So, i guess i didnt know that i need to append to the beginning of the file and write this at the top of an existing file. I found out that when i run my code this way, it replaces all the text in the file with just what ive written.

Would i need to use the prepend function?
'def line_prepender(filename, line):'
    'with open(filename, 'r+') as f:'
        'content = f.read()'
        'f.seek(0, 0)'
        'f.write(line.rstrip('\r\n') + '\n' + content)'

Comment: Where in the code did you put that? And do i have to input the "Filename" directly into that line of code? Or am able to set up everything in my GUI and then have the Save button do the Append?

Sorry for all the questions and thank you for helping me!

Comment: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test'
Stack trace:
 >  File "C:\Python_Stuff\Master AA GUI\GUI Master.py", line 39, in <module>
 >    with open('Test', 'r') as original: data = original.read()
Loaded '__main__'
Loaded 'runpy'
The program 'python.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: i edited the function 'file_save()': Try it , it worked well, if you get a probem tell me for post all the code